# How to read out tag from xml?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have some problem to read out info from this xml:

```
<entry number="50" date="2011-01-29">
 <name>Info text about account</name>
 <row account="1930" debit="0" credit="2051"/>
 <row account="1471" debit="410" credit="0"/>
 <row account="4404" debit="1641" credit="0"/>
</entry>
```

I use this code

```
def printInfoOfVerification():
    valFound = 0
        print("Now system will print information about a verification nr in xml:")
        val = input("Enter verification number: ")
    verificationNumbr = xmltree.iter('entry')
    for i in verificationNumbr:
        if (i.attrib['number']) == val:
                valFound = 1
                    print("Verification number:",val, "found")
                    print("Info about verification:")
                    print(i.attrib['date'])
            if valFound == 0:
                    print("Verification number not found:",val)
```

If "val" is = 50 this will produce:

```
Verification number: 50 found
Info about verification:
2011-01-29
```

But the problem is, I also want to print the info in the tag "name", so for this example it should look like this:

```
Verification number: 50 found
Info about verification:
2011-01-29
Info text about account
```

I have tried to read in name tag with xmltree.iter('name') and other ways but without success :( Do anyone know how to do this?
Thx

Comment: What exactly is `xmltree`? I take it you are using the xml.etree module.

Comment: Yes , import it like this `from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree as ET xmltree = ET()`

Answer (score 1):

My personal choice using lxml with Python 2.7.x.

```
from lxml import etree

data = """
<entry number="50" date="2011-01-29">
 <name>Info text about account</name>
 <row account="1930" debit="0" credit="2051"/>
 <row account="1471" debit="410" credit="0"/>
 <row account="4404" debit="1641" credit="0"/>
</entry>
"""

tree = etree.fromstring(data)
entry = tree.xpath('/entry[@number="49"]')
if not entry:
    print 'No entry found'

entry = tree.xpath('/entry[@number="50"]')[0]
print 'found'
print 'Info: {}'.format(entry.get('date'))
print entry.find('name').text
for row in entry.findall('row'):
    print 'account =', row.get('account') # etc...
```

Output:

```
No entry found
found
Info: 2011-01-29
Info text about account
account = 1930
account = 1471
account = 4404
```

Possible convenience lookup (to get access to nodes via number quickly):

```
lookup = dict( (int(node.get('number')), node) for node in tree.xpath('/entry') )
```

Then access via:

```
lookup[50].findall('account')
```

etc...

Comment: Thx! So maybe not possible use ElementTree in a good way here...? The xml file I will loop through have hundreds of numbers that should be possible to search for `<entry number="50"`

Comment: Have edited a line to include a lookup dict that should make querying more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Thx for helping!! I also found a way of using ElementTree to fix the problem which make this print out:

```
Verification number: 50 found
Info about verification:
2011-01-29
Namn: Info text about account
Konto: 1930, Debit:     0, Kredit:  2051
Konto: 1471, Debit:   410, Kredit:     0
Konto: 4404, Debit:  1641, Kredit:     0
```

The code I used:

```
def printInfoOfVerification():
        print("Now system will print information about a verification nr in xml:")
        val = input("Enter verification number: ")
        verificationNumbr = xmltree.iter('entry')
        for entry in verificationNumbr:
                if (entry.attrib['number']) == val:
                        valFound = 1
                        print("Verification number:",val, "found")
                        print("Info about verification:")
                        print(entry.attrib['date'])
                        findInfoAboutVerification(entry)
        if valFound == 0:
                print("Verification number not found:",val)


def findInfoAboutVerification(entry):
        verificationText = entry.iter()
        for node in verificationText:
                if "name" in node.tag:
                        print('Namn: %s' % node.text)
                if "comment" in node.tag:
                        print('Kommentar: %s' % node.text)
                if "row" in node.tag:
                        print('Konto: %s, Debit: %s, Kredit: %s' % (node.attrib['account'], node.attrib['debit'].rjust(5), node.attrib['credit'].rjust(5)))
```